# How can I translate this regular expression from Perl to Java?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose, we need to match:

> Anything or nothing, followed by a dot of which there may be 0 or 1,
>   followed by the word "network", where N may come in lower case or
>   upper case.

This works fine in Perl:

```
^.*(\.?)[Nn]etwork$
```

How would you match this in Java? I tried

```
(.*)\\.?(N|n)etwork$
```

but "blah.Network" does not match

Comment: Wouldn't `^.*[Nn]etwork$` match exactly the same? Why do you need to match the optional dot separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
^.*\\.?[Nn]etwork$
```

as in

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("^.*\\.?[Nn]etwork$");
```

(The parentheses around the dot are unnecessary anyway).

Comment: Note that the _regex_ is `^.*\.?[Nn]etwork$`; the extra backslash is simply part of the mechanism for writing this as a Java string literal.